# Braintree Drop-In UI Paypal integration not loading

Tags: c#, blazor-webassembly, .net-6.0, braintree, visual-studio-2022

I have loaded the drop in UI, my auth works, the UI loads correctly, but when I click on Paypal Checkout, a new window pops up, it remains on about:blank for 5-10s and then it closes.  The UI then states: ⚠ Something went wrong on our end.

In the console I get:

```json
{
country: "US"
env: "sandbox"
errtype: "[object Error]"
host: "www.sandbox.paypal.com"
lang: "en"
pageID: "cd1b0e1c50"
path: "/smart/button"
prev_corr_ids: ""
referer: "https://localhost:7244"
stack: "Error: No ack for postMessage postrobot_method in https://www.sandbox.paypal.com in 10000ms\n    at o (https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.min.js:2:134213)"
timestamp: 1649373277263
uid: {{uId}}
ver: "4.0.334"
windowID: "3a6eb34307"
}
```

Here is the initialization config for the drop-in UI:

```json
{
authorization: "*********"
container: "#braintree_container"
paypal:{
   amount: "$487.88"
   currency: "USD"
   flow: "checkout"
   }
}
```

I have used known working credentials to no avail, and it still does not work, despite them being known good credentials. In digging into the requests, it seems like somewhere after the `web.paypal-checkout.createPayment` POST call. it sets up the billing agreement seemingly successfully, gets the ectoken, makes the `UpdateClientConfig` graphql call, but never makes the call out to the `sandbox.paypal.com/smart/api/checkout/{{ectoken}}/appData?` endpoint.

In the internal application, it seems to fail after the updateClientConfig call. It never populates the popup window, nor places the overlay.  Attached are the HAR files for the internal app and the working codepen for comparison.  These HAR files comprise all calls made after the Paypal gold button was clicked.  I am inlining the relevant responses for redundancy.

INTERNAL—NON-WORKING SOLUTION

---

Analytics payload:

```json
{
    "analytics": [
        {
            "kind": "web.dropin.selected.paypal",
            "timestamp": 1649854187
        }
    ],
    "_meta": {
        "merchantAppId": "localhost:7244",
        "platform": "web",
        "sdkVersion": "3.80.0",
        "source": "client",
        "integration": "dropin2",
        "integrationType": "dropin2",
        "sessionId": {{sId}},
        "dropinVersion": "1.31.2"
    },
    "braintreeLibraryVersion": "3.80.0",
    "authorizationFingerprint": {{token}}
}
```

Setup billing agreement response:

```json
{
    "agreementSetup": {
        "tokenId": {{paymentToken}},
        "approvalUrl": "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/agreements/approve?nolegacy=1\u0026ba_token={{paymentToken}}"
    }
}
```

ectoken response:

```json
{
    "ack": "success",
    "data": {
        "type": "ba-token",
        "token": {{paymentToken}}
    },
    "meta": {
        "calc": "6496f6f13b1bb",
        "rlog": "rZJvnqaaQhLn%2FnmWT8cSUueWscmrtUHe5Y1Bd%2FeqyvyOTq66rSXAciiXRg7dClMl1o2iporwJbYz7mI0k8X%2B5ryRC%2FRgCX6v_18022f916a7"
    },
    "server": {{serverId}}
}
```

UpdateClientConfig graphql:

Request:

```graphql
            mutation UpdateClientConfig(
                $paymentToken : String!,
                $fundingSource : ButtonFundingSourceType!,
                $integrationArtifact : IntegrationArtifactType!,
                $userExperienceFlow : UserExperienceFlowType!,
                $productFlow : ProductFlowType!,
                $buttonSessionID : String
            ) {
                updateClientConfig(
                    token: $paymentToken,
                    fundingSource: $fundingSource,
                    integrationArtifact: $integrationArtifact,
                    userExperienceFlow: $userExperienceFlow,
                    productFlow: $productFlow,
                    buttonSessionID: $buttonSessionID
                )
            }
        
{
  "paymentToken": {{paymentToken}},
  "fundingSource": "paypal",
  "integrationArtifact": "JS_V4",
  "userExperienceFlow": "INCONTEXT",
  "productFlow": "SMART_PAYMENT_BUTTONS",
  "buttonSessionID": null
}
```

Response:

```json
{
  "data": {
    "updateClientConfig": null
  },
  "extensions": {
    "tracing": {
      "version": 1,
      "startTime": "2022-04-13T12:49:51.854Z",
      "endTime": "2022-04-13T12:49:51.938Z",
      "duration": 84116563,
      "execution": {
        "resolvers": [
          {
            "path": [
              "updateClientConfig"
            ],
            "parentType": "Mutation",
            "fieldName": "updateClientConfig",
            "returnType": "Boolean",
            "startOffset": 1044862,
            "duration": 83027846
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    "correlationId": "3535ba30e2627"
  }
}
```

WORKING CODEPEN SOLUTION

---

Analytics payload:

```json
{
    "analytics": [
        {
            "kind": "web.paypal-checkout.createPayment",
            "isAsync": false,
            "timestamp": 1649854795783
        }
    ],
    "braintreeLibraryVersion": "braintree/web/3.85.3",
    "_meta": {
        "merchantAppId": "cdpn.io",
        "platform": "web",
        "sdkVersion": "3.85.3",
        "source": "client",
        "integration": "dropin2",
        "integrationType": "dropin2",
        "sessionId": {{sId}},
        "dropinVersion": "1.33.1"
    },
    "authorizationFingerprint": {{token}}
}
```

Setup billing agreement response:

```json
{
    "agreementSetup": {
        "tokenId": {{paymentToken}},
        "approvalUrl": "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/agreements/approve?nolegacy=1\u0026ba_token={{paymentToken}}"
    }
}
```

ectoken response:

```json
{
    "ack": "success",
    "data": {
        "type": "ba-token",
        "token": {{paymentToken}}
    },
    "meta": {
        "calc": "3f508c09dd431",
        "rlog": "rZJvnqaaQhLn%2FnmWT8cSUueWscmrtUHe5Y1Bd%2FeqyvyOTq66rSXAciiXRg7dClMl1o2iporwJbYz7mI0k8X%2B5vvp6t7dnU%2B%2B_180230253f6"
    },
    "server": {{serverId}}
}
```

UpdateClientConfig graphql:

Request:

```graphql
            mutation UpdateClientConfig(
                $paymentToken : String!,
                $fundingSource : ButtonFundingSourceType!,
                $integrationArtifact : IntegrationArtifactType!,
                $userExperienceFlow : UserExperienceFlowType!,
                $productFlow : ProductFlowType!,
                $buttonSessionID : String
            ) {
                updateClientConfig(
                    token: $paymentToken,
                    fundingSource: $fundingSource,
                    integrationArtifact: $integrationArtifact,
                    userExperienceFlow: $userExperienceFlow,
                    productFlow: $productFlow,
                    buttonSessionID: $buttonSessionID
                )
            }
        
{
  "paymentToken": {{paymentToken}},
  "fundingSource": "paypal",
  "integrationArtifact": "JS_V4",
  "userExperienceFlow": "INCONTEXT",
  "productFlow": "SMART_PAYMENT_BUTTONS",
  "buttonSessionID": null
}
```

Response:

```json
{
  "data": {
    "updateClientConfig": null
  },
  "extensions": {
    "tracing": {
      "version": 1,
      "startTime": "2022-04-13T12:59:57.407Z",
      "endTime": "2022-04-13T12:59:57.491Z",
      "duration": 84834935,
      "execution": {
        "resolvers": [
          {
            "path": [
              "updateClientConfig"
            ],
            "parentType": "Mutation",
            "fieldName": "updateClientConfig",
            "returnType": "Boolean",
            "startOffset": 1231858,
            "duration": 83540568
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    "correlationId": "f6e5896873a1"
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't see enough details to quickly analyze or reproduce, so voting to close. Contact Braintree's support and provide more information

Comment: I'm not sure what other information you are wanting, but immediately voting to close right after the question opening without actually asking for what information you feel you need to appropriately assist someone is being disingenuous to the spirit of this site at best.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: And I provided that. A braintree config is all you need besides a sandbox account to do what I am doing. That's literally how the drop in ui works. I am obviously not going to provide any of my keys, but suffice it to say we have other integrations working on this account with a similar setup.

Comment: I can take that put it into the drop in and run it by replacing the token values right now, so how is it not reproducible? Maybe if you use words to explain what you feel is "missing" then I can provide context or the actual thing that's missing. But instead, you decide to be vague and just point to a policy that I well know, (being here longer than you) despite my providing the only pieces of data someone with a basic knowledge of the braintree drop in ui (as I have) would need to verify the issue.

Comment: There's no context or references. I've used the Drop in UI but I have no idea what to do with your config. It doesn't appear minimal, many optional things like the shipping override you can eliminate one by one, see if the issue still reproduces w/o them. It also looks like you're referencing variables/functions not included in the question (OrderState? GetAvalaraTaxRate? they don't appear in any Braintree sample I am familiar with). It basically looks like you copy and pasted this without any attempt to make it minimal or reproducible outside your environment.

Comment: I have simplified my object as requested.  AFAIK it is as simple as is possible for the integration I am attempting.  Do I now qualify to be helped?

Comment: It would help to also note what specific implementation guide to plug that config into, but yes that does look better, I retracted my close. Have you tested with an alternate Braintree sandbox account and with a clean implementation, to confirm same issue?

Comment: As stated, this is using the drop-in guide (https://developer.paypal.com/braintree/docs/guides/drop-in/setup-and-integration).  I have not tried with an alternate as duplicating the exact setup would be very difficult since this is a corporate setup and this is a clean implementation that I am currently writing.

Comment: we used a config from another application where it does work, and it still does not work.

Comment: Have you tried different sandbox credentials yet?

Comment: yes, and it still does not work, despite them being known good credentials.  In digging into the nitty gritty, it seems like somewhere after the `web.paypal-checkout.createPayment` POST call.  it sets up the billing agreement seemingly successfully, gets the ectoken, makes the `UpdateClientConfig` graphql call, but never makes the call out to the `https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/smart/api/checkout/{{ectoken}}/appData?` endpoint

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For my specific issue, VS2022 opens a chrome window with default debug switches that interfere with the functionality of the Braintree Paypal integration.  specifically, it seems to be the `--disable-background-networking` switch.  Once I disabled this switch, Paypal worked fine. Opening a new window and navigating to the path or using a different browser will also solve the issue.